# Dynamic titles for each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make dynamic titles for each page of my application.

My approach:
In application.html.erb I set this:

```
<title><%= titles %></title>
```

And I added this on ApllicationHelper.rb

```
  def titles
    if request.original_fullpath == "/"
      return "Find Web Designers and Developers • AwesomeWeb"
    end 
  end
```

I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in HomeController#index
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

I am not sure if this is even a good approach. But I think you understand what I am trying to do. Even if this approach works its fine with me. Any suggestions of how can I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a better approach for this: [`content_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for).

In your application.html.erb:

```
<title><%= yield :title %></title>
```

In your views (say, /users/new.html.erb)

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  Create New User
<% end %>
```

No need to hardcode all possible values in application_helper.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the dot symbol is not an ASCII symbol. For this reason, depending on the Ruby version, you may need to specify that the file `application_helper` is a different encoding.

Add the following comment

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the very top of the file.

About the approach, I would suggest to determine the content of the title in the views. You can create a simple helper that stores the title

```
def title(string = nil)
  @_title = string if string
end
```

and then in your view use it as a setter

```
<% title "Find Web Designers and Developers • AwesomeWeb" %>
```

in the layout, use it as a getter

```
<title><%= title %></title>
```